# change in temperature vs change of temperature

Tags: word-usage

> The change **in** temperature may be as much as 200' C.
>   The change **of** temperature may be as much as 200' C.

What is the difference  between *the change **in** temperature* and  *the change **of** temperature*?

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82037/the-sudden-change-in-temperature-or-the-sudden-change-of-temperature  _"The sudden change **in** temperature or the sudden change **of** temperature_"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a lot of difference, but I interpret it this way.

Using *in* more likely concerns the *measurement* change of temperature.

> The change **in** temperature may be as much as 200' C.

Using *of* more likely concerns the *effect* of the temperature change.

> The change **of** temperature caused the pottery to crack.